# Messages does not show HTC Desire Z

Tags: sms, htc-desire-z

I have a problem with my HTC Desire Z, when I open messages it’s just blank, I have the option to write messages but I can see any of my old ones. I have tried restarting it and taking in an out the sim-card.

Is this a known problem? Anyone have a solution?

Answer (score 1):

Are you capable of receiving new sms? Do new SMS messages pop up?

If you're using the default or stock messaging app, try installing another app like [Handcent](https://market.android.com/details?id=com.handcent.nextsms) or [GoSMS](https://market.android.com/details?id=com.jb.mms) and see if the same behaviour is repeated.

Else, try clearing all the messages stored and see. Within the default messaging app, there's an option to specify the Message Centre number - you need to verify that the number entered is what your service provider has assigned.

If that doesn't result in any improvement, see if a Factory Reset will help. Beware that a Factory Reset will erase all user data.

Answer (score 0):

Is your internal storage full? Usually you won't receive any message when your internal memory is getting full, but it could potentially be your problem.